# Bootstrap form validation for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

i am using bootstrap 3.0 form validation JavaScript code from https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator with ASP.NET and it works fine, but when i add runat server to my form controls it does not work please help me on this problem.

Comment: Well runat will generally create its own control ids (unless specified otherwise) for the controls?

Comment: it works fine like this: <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm"/>
and it have a problem when i add runat = "server"  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"  class="form-control input-sm" runat="server"/>

Comment: after running the code the input control looks:<input name="ctl00$RightContent$firstname" type="text" id="RightContent_firstname" class="form-control input-sm">, how to avoid ASP.NET from generating unique ID?

Answer (score 2):

RunAt="server" changes names / id's of controls. Instead of:

```
...
fields: {
    firstname: {
        ... validiation code
        }
}
```

try this:

```
fields: {
    <%= firstname.UniqueID %>: {
       ... validiation code
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are using ASP.net 4.0 and you can guarantee uniqueness in the name, you can add ClientIDMode="Static" to the textbox to prevent ASP.net from appending to your Id.